# Why don't we include $y$ approaches to $y_0$ as a limit?

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, slope

[image]

How comes we only use $x$ approaches to $x_0$ when $y$ approaches $y_0$ is equally important. Why don't we include $y$ approaches $y_0$?

Comment: Concretely, what if we had $y = \sin x$, and we wanted to find the derivative at $(0, 0)$? If we require $x \to 0$, then that gives us $y \to 0$. However, if we know that $y \to 0$, that doesn't mean we've got the right point. It could be the case that $x \to \pi$ and $y \to 0$, in which case the limit of the slope of the secant is $0$, which isn't the number we want.

Comment: Since y is a continuous function of x, and $y(x_0)= y_0$, as x approaches $x_0$, y necessarily approaches $y_0$.  It is not necessary to say both.

Answer (score 2):

Because $y$ depends on $x$... The points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ belong to the graphic of a function $f$, so $y_1=f(x_1)$ and $y_0=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much